# How many votes do i need to changea percentage?

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods

I got an app with a 4.4631 rating after 176 reviews. Every user can review it and rate it from 1 to 5 points. How many 5 points reviews do i need to reach 4.6 and then 4.7?

I've googled about percentage change but I don't understand how it relates to my problem. Please help.

Comment: You appear to have received $4.4631\times176=785.5056$ votes which means either the app's rating system is inaccurate or that the rating calculation is non-linear.

Comment: what do you mean with the rating calculation being non-linear?

Comment: Or reviews $\neq$ votes.

Comment: It is possible that the higher points are accorded a higher rating value but not in direct proportion (i.e. a linear relationship).Perhaps they reward you with significantly higher rating if you receive more 5 point scores, so unless you know what their model is, it may be impossible to accurately estimate how many new 5 point scores you need to reach a given target. It may be less than you think. Expect a convex function rather than a concave one. They are hardly likely to penalise you for consistently good scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rating of $4.4631$ is the average of the $176$ individual ratings, so the app must have received a total of about $4.4631\cdot176=785.5056$ points from users. This probably represents an actual total of $785.5$ rating points, the $0.0056$ being the result of rounding $\frac{785.5}{176}$ to four decimal places. There is no way to get $4.4631$ from $176$ users if ratings have to be integers, so it appears that half-point ratings are possible.

Suppose that you now get $n$ $5$-point ratings and nothing lower. You will then have a total of $785.5+5n$ rating points from $176+n$ users, so your average will be

$$\frac{785.5+5n}{176+n}\;,$$

and you want that to be at least $4.6$. Set it equal to $4.6$ and solve for $n$: if

$$\frac{785.5+5n}{176+n}=4.6\;,\tag{1}$$

then

$$785.5+5n=4.6(176+n)=809.6+4.6n\;,$$

so $0.4n=24.1$, and

$$n=\frac{24.1}{0.4}=60.25\;.$$

You can’t actually get $60.25$ ratings, so you need $61$ ratings of $5$ with nothing lower in order to reach $4.6$, and that actually gives you

$$\frac{785.5+5\cdot61}{176+61}\approx4.6013\;,$$

rounded to four decimal places. Replacing $4.6$ with $4.7$ in equation $(1)$ and solving in the same way will give you the other desired number.

Comment: I never expected the number to be so high. That's almost a third of the reviews have right now

Comment: @agapito: The fact that you have quite a few reviews is actually part of the problem: the more you have, the more it takes to shift the average by a given amount.

Comment: so that means that every review will diminish the impact that the next review would have in the rating, right?

Comment: @agapito: Yes, that’s right. If you have one review, the next one is $50$% of your user input; if you have $1000$ reviews, the next one is a mere drop in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you can't do this unless you can find the exact amount of people that voted each number. Assuming you have access to that, what you could do is:

1. Assign each rating a numerical point value, so 1 would be 20 points, 2 - 40, 3 - 60, 4 - 80, and 5 - 100
2. Then multiply the number of total reviews by 100, so $176*100$, which equals 17,600
3. Now, take the amount of each rating and multiply it by the corresponding point value. i.e with 25 ratings of 1, you multiply $25*20$.
4. Add all the products from the last step
5. Now solve for $x/17600 = y/100$, where $x$ is the sum from step 4, and $y$ is the percent out of 100 that it equals
6. Once you have $y$(as a percent), do $y*5$ to get the current 4.xxxx
7. Keep adding 100 to $x$ and repeat steps 5&6

I guess this really doesn't answer your question, but I provided how to do it yourself. Hope it helps!